# How to specify the correct path for Azure PS Script in VSTS _git for release pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm working on an Azure DevOps release pipeline that utilizes an Azure PowerShell script. I've committed this script alongside my code in VSTS _git. However, I've encountered an issue where I'm unsure about the correct path to reference the script in the pipeline configuration.

I've tried several path combinations, but none seem to work. Here's a screenshot of my current configuration: .[image]

Comment: Use the file browser icon at the right hand side to explore the artifacts available and choose if you find your PowerShell script.

Comment: No my friend, I tried that too, but unable to locate my .ps1 file there

Comment: Are you building the artifacts using the VSO build definition before running Release definition? In that case, we need to copy all files to artifacts folder which are mandatory at Release Definition.

Comment: Refer Copy Artifacts Step & Publish Artifacts Step online; add those if you are missing in build definition. Artifacts should be available in the system folder named, '$Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory\YourFolderName'.

Comment: It’s working good now, thank you Ashok for the help. I am marking it as an Answer for my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer **Copy Artifacts Step** & **Publish Artifacts** Step online; add those if you are missing in the build definition.Artifacts should be available in the system folder named,`$Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory\YourFolderName`.